# GCC compilation - where the __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4 symbol comes from?

Tags: centos, rhel, gcc, c++

I'm using GCC 4.7.2 from [devtoolset](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/) package on CentOS 5 (CentOS 5 because we need compatibility with old Linuxes, and GCC 4.7 because it optimizes better than 4.4).

There is one symbols that prevents my binaries from running on RHEL4: `__stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4`. It is included only in some C++ programs and the `-fno-stack-protector` flag doesn't help.

Here is minimal program that reproduces the problem (but the same using `stdio.h` works):

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int i=0; i < argc; i++)
        std::cout << " " << argv[i];
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with optimization (`-O`/`-O2`) it references `__stack_chk_fail`.

```
$ g++ -fno-stack-protector -O2 foo.cc
$ readelf -s a.out | grep chk
    15: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4 (5)
   105: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2
```

Any idea why this symbol gets here and how to get rid of it?

Just in case, full `readelf` output and `gcc -v` is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=jDZ0q7n9).

Edit: This problem may be specific to Red Hat Developer Toolset 1.1. With default CentOS compiler `__stack_chk_fail` is not referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symbol comes from `libstdc++_nonshared.a`.

Unlike GCC from the distro, GCC from devtoolset has non-shared part of libstdc++.
libstdc++.so in GCC 4.7 is a linker script that uses libstdc++ from GCC 4.1 and extra functions linked statically:

```
$ cat /opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/i386-CentOS-linux/4.7.2/libstdc++.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
INPUT ( /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -lstdc++_nonshared )
```

After recompiling `libstdc++_nonshared.a` with disabled stack protector the final program can be run on RHEL4.

Answer (score 0):

It comes with GLibC. Build against an older GLibC.

You can tell GCC 4.7 to emit optimized assembly code and then assemble and link that on an older system

Comment: well, the symbol is *defined* in glibc, as can be seen from versioning `@GLIBC_2.4`, but why is it *referenced* in this simple program, regardless of `-fno-stack-protector`? Moving assembly around can be done for this minimal example, but the real project has thousands of files and complex build system.